# Jmeter standard and dashboard report analysis

Tags: jmeter, report, dashboard

i am new to jmeter.I am facing issue in annalizing the Jmeter Graph.Like Hits per second,transaction per seconds,Response time vs response time etc?I need to know the Jmeter standard and need to compare with the Dashboard report generated.Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to "compare" here? Both [JMeter Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) and graphs from [JMeter Plugins custom charts](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Start/#Graphs) utilize the same source data: [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) so all the charts will be the same.

With regards to "standard" - there is no single guidance for test results analysis, you need to treat each case individually. Just make sure to go via each [metric and KPI](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420665-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites) you're able to get and correlate them to see the relationships and detect anomalies

Given the assumption: on ideal system the throughput (number of transactions per second) will increase by the same factor as the load (number of virtual users) increase.

However in reality up to certain point the throughput will be increasing but under a certain load you will notice that the number of virtual users is increasing but the throughput remains the same (or starts decreasing) or errors start occurring. This point indicates the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing).